# Trigger an analytics event when user see specific screen

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-redux, react-navigation

**DESCRIPTION**

I have an app that should trigger an analytics event just once at a specific screen when a component is shown to the user.
i.e: if the user open the application and land to home screen and the component  is showing, then the analytics event should be sent. If the user navigate to Settings screen and the component  is there, then the event should trigger, but if the user navigate back to home screen, the event shouldn't trigger. Just have to be called once per screen.

If the user quit the app completely, the event should fire again once reopen it

**STACK**

- react-native
- react-navigation
- react-redux

**WHAT I'VE DONE**

I've tried to use the `useIsFocused` hook with `useEffect`and `useRef` but it turns that when the screen is rerender for an async fetch event, the state inside my useEffect is reset and the analytics event trigger again, which is not the expected behavior.

```
const isHasBeenFocused = useRef()

const isFocused = useIsFocused()

useEffect(()=>{

if(isHasBeenFocused.current){

    return;

}

isFocused && dispatch(analyticsEvent, payload)

isHasBeenFocused.current = isFocused

}, [])
```

This is my approach, but I don't know if it's the correct one or if there's another, better option.

Hope anyone could help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the analytics event to fire only once for the lifetime of the app installation, you could use [AsyncStorage](https://github.com/react-native-async-storage/async-storage) for flags like this. AsyncStorage used to be a core RN module but is now community-based.

This will persist until the app is uninstalled.

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    const check = async () => {
      const hasReported = await AsyncStorage.getItem('yourKey');
      if (hasReported) return;
      AsyncStorage.setItem('yourKey', true);
      dispatch(analyticsEvent, payload);
    };
    check();
  }, []);
```

If you want the analytics to fire once per session, you could use the same solution with an AppState listener to reset the value to something falsy when the app is backgrounded. There's a good example of using AppState [in the React Native docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/next/appstate).

If you need the value to persist across app installs, the best solution is to store it in your backend.